# How can I properly chain custom methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, method-chaining

I am trying to do a chaining method for the following two methods. After running this code, I kept getting the following output:

```
#<SimpleMath:0x007fc85898ab70>%
```

My question is: what is the proper way of chaining methods in `Ruby`?

Here is my codes:

```
class SimpleMath


    def add(a,b=0)
        a + b
        return self
    end


    def subtract(a,b=0)
         a - b
        return self
    end

end
newNumber = SimpleMath.new()
print newNumber.add(2,3).add(2)
```

Comment: What were you expecting/hoping for?

Comment: That *is* the proper way to chain methods. You return an instance, and that's precisely what's being displayed.

Comment: When I do newNumber.add(2,3), I wanted to get a 5 and not #<SimpleMath:0x007fc85898ab70>%

Comment: ... Then you'd need to change the default string representation of the class.

Comment: Also, something like `add(2)` is meaningless if you're not keeping the result in the instance.

Comment: You'd also need to be storing the results of those additions/subtractions somewhere

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
class SimpleMath
  def initialize
    @result = 0
  end

  #1 add function
  def add(val)
    @result += val
    self
  end

  #2 Subtract function
  def subtract(val)
    @result -= val
    self
  end

  def to_s
    @result
  end
end

newNumber = SimpleMath.new
p newNumber.add(2).add(2).subtract(1)
```

For any number of arguments

```
class SimpleMath
  def initialize
    @result = 0
  end

  #1 add function
  def add(*val)
    @result += val.inject(&:+)
    self
  end

  #2 Subtract function
  def subtract(*val)
    @result -= val.inject(&:+)
    self
  end

  def to_s
    @result
  end
end

newNumber = SimpleMath.new
p newNumber.add(1, 1).add(1, 1, 1, 1).subtract(1)
```

Comment: Rustam, I wanted for the methods to take at least two parameters.

Comment: @visBar here are you go

Comment: That's very neat. Thank you.

Comment: How can I also make it receive an array as a param?

Comment: @visBar, use `val.flatten.inject(&:+)`. This way you can pass arrays or numbers or arrays and numbers...

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov- this `newNumber.add(1, 1).add(1, 1, 1, 1).subtract(1)` gives me `<SimpleMath:0x007fcb7fa1c7a8 @result=5>` that good *But* if I have to get just `5`. How might I can get ? second How Might I can call a callback on each function. Like `newNumber.add(1, 1)` shoudl gives 2

Answer (score 6):

Let's define an instance of your class `SimpleMath`:

```
sm = SimpleMath.new #=> #<SimpleMath:0x000001020ca820>
```

Three things to note here:

- `sm` is a variable.  In Ruby, variables are represented by lower case letters, optionally separated with underscores (e.g., `my_var`).
- while it's OK to add `()` after `new`, when `new` has no arguments (aka "parameters"), that's optional and not usually done.
- if the keyword `return` is not present, Ruby returns the last calculation performed by the method.  Here you would generally write the last line as simply `self`, and that would be returned.  Alas, that matters not, as returning `self`, with or without the keyword `return`, is not what you want.

Try the following in IRB:

```
sm.add(2) #=> #<SimpleMath:0x000001020ca820>
```

You no doubt were expecting this to return `2+0 #=> 2`, but instead it returned `self`, which, as you can see above, is in fact `sm` (`#<SimpleMath:0x000001020ca820>`).

You can fix this by simply removing the line:

```
return self
```

from `add` and `subtract`:

```
class SimpleMath
  def add(a,b=0)
    a + b
  end

  def subtract(a,b=0)
    a - b
  end
end
```

Now

```
sm = SimpleMath.new
sm.add(2) #=> 2
```

However, if we try to chain another `add`, we have another problem:

```
sm.add(2).add(2,3) #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `add' for 2:Fixnum
```

This message is very clear: the class `Fixnum`, of which `2` is an instance, has no instance method named `add`.  That's because you defined it for the class `SimpleMath`, not for `Fixnum`.

When Ruby executes `sm.add(2).add(3,4)`, it first computes `sm.add(2) #=> 2`, which reduces the expression to `2.add(3,4)`.  It then attempts to send the method `add` (with its two parameters) to `2`, but finds the class `2.class #=> Fixnum` has no instance method `add`; hence the exception.

We can correct that error by defining these methods for class `Fixnum` instead:

```
class Fixnum
  def add(a,b=0)
    a + b
  end

  def subtract(a,b=0)
    a - b
  end
end
```

You can confirm that these methods have been added to the `Fixnum` class by running:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.sort
```

Now, another problem:

```
sm = Fixnum.new #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Fixnum:Class
```

Oh, my, the class `Fixnum` has no `new` method! That's because the instances of `Fixnum` are integers, which cannot be created.  You can easily confirm that integers are instances of `Fixnum`:

```
72.class #=> Fixnum
-3.class #=> Fixnum
```

So we can invoke the `add` method by sending it to *any* `Fixnum` instance:

```
72.add(2) #=> 2
-3.add(2) #=> 2
```

Now let's try to chain `add` operations:

```
72.add(2).add(3,4)       #=> 7
72.add(2000000).add(3,4) #=> 7
```

No exception, but no chaining.  The way to fix this is to change the methods yet again:

```
class Fixnum
  def add(b=0)
    puts "in add, self = #{self}, b = #{b}"
    self + b
  end

  def subtract(b=0)
    puts "in subtract, self = #{self}, b = #{b}"
    self - b
  end
end
```

I've added a `puts` statement in each method in case more debugging is needed.  We'll remove these when the code works properly.  Let's test:

```
2.add(3)                    #=> 5
  in add, self = 2, b = 3
5.add                       #=> 5
  in add, self = 5, b = 0
5.add(7)                    #=> 12
  in add, self = 5, b = 7
2.add(3).add.add(7)         #=> 12
  in add, self = 2, b = 3
  in add, self = 5, b = 0
  in add, self = 5, b = 7

2.subtract(5)               #=> -3
  in subtract, self = 2, b = 5
-3.subtract                 #=> -3
  in subtract, self = -3, b = 0
2.subtract(5).subtract      #=> -3
  in subtract, self = 2, b = 5
  in subtract, self = -3, b = 0

2.add(3).subtract(5).add(7) #=>  7
  in add, self = 2, b = 3
  in subtract, self = 5, b = 5
  in add, self = 0, b = 7
```

Success!  Get it?

Comment: Cary, thank you for clarifying. I think my understand of chaining is solid now.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to build pipeline via [chainable_methods gem](https://github.com/akitaonrails/chainable_methods).

[Described in the article](https://medium.com/@merqlove/ruby-pipelines-is-easy-7601ada5a174#.3gmmqgswz)

```
require 'chainable_methods'

module SimpleMath
  include ChainableMethods

  def add(a, b=0)
    a + b
  end

  def subtract(a, b=0)
    a - b    
  end
end

SimpleMath.
  chain_from(5).
  add(5).
  add(5).
  subtract(3).
  unwrap
```

Answer (score -1):

This fellow ([tjackiw.tumblr.com](http://tjackiw.tumblr.com/post/23155838377/interview-challenge-ruby-method-chaining)) uses this as an interview question and gives a very clean walkthough of how & why the correct answer is similar to the following:

```
class Interpreter

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def at(time)
    @time = time
    self
  end

  def when(date)
    @date = date
    self
  end

  def we(*people)
    @people = people
    self
  end

  def going(where)
    @where = where
    self
  end

  def output
    [@people.join(' and '), "are going", @where, @date, "at", @time].join(' ')
  end

end
```