# How does one pass an array as a param in a method?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, param

I would like to pass an array as an argument with many values as possible for this method. For example, if I entered `[1,2,3]` into `add([1,2,3]`, I should receive the sum value of the array.

```
def add(a, b)
    a + b
end

def subtract(a, b)
a - b
end
```

Since I am new to Ruby, I am not sure how to go about this. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641682/how-can-i-properly-chain-custom-methods-in-ruby), I'm guessing you want to be able to distinguish between array arguments and numeric arguments. Try using the `kind_of?` method and branching based on the result. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527888/ruby-test-for-array) question for other advice (using the `responds_to?` method is more idiomatic).

```
def add(val)
  if (val.kind_of?(Array))
    # add each element
  else
    @result += val
  end
end
```

To do the addition, you'll want to use the `each` method to perform an action for every element of the array.

```
val.each do |x|
  @result += x
end
```

Comment: Why bother with the `kind_of?`, just go straight for `if val.respond_to? :each`

Comment: @iain No. I would use `#instance_of?`.. There are lots who can respond to `#each`.. Or, You can either do `respond_to?(:to_ary)`... `#kind_of` for *kindness* and `#instance_of?` for *strictness*.. :-) It is up to you what you want to be.. Loll.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to answer the question literally just in case visBar later wanted to distinguish between other collections. You wouldn't want to do the same kind of `each` over an array and a hash.

Comment: @ArupRakshit There *are* lots that can respond to `each`, so document the default usage (for an Array-like collection) and let the method take a block too, the caller should know what it's passing. Use `instance_of` for something like this in a codebase I'm responsible for and you wouldn't get past a code review ;)

Answer (score 12):

The usual way of doing this is to pass a variable number of arguments, which I assume from your question are [Numeric](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Numeric.html):

```
def add_em_up(*args)
  args.reduce(:+)
end

add_em_up(1,2,3,4)    #=> 10
add_em_up(1,2,3.5,4)  #=> 10.5
```

Comment: +1 for `#reduce` and +1 for *Greedy* operator. It is really greedy..Huhh.. :-)

Comment: I find this a bit amusing.  18 hours after posting I've received 10 upvotes for an answer that falls somewhat short of, let's say, "mind-bending", yet many brilliant contributions I've made in the past have yet to earn a single +1.  I guess that's just life at SO.

Comment: I agree, It is SO life :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think Andrew's post is fine but you're more likely to see the `is_a` method like this:

```
def add(val)
  if val.is_a?(Array)
    do something
  else
    @result += val
  end
end
```